# How to get data without knowing key of json in react native

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, react-native

In response i get this king of data, here in data object there is various items but there key are kind of common so how can i get that data and add in my categories list.

```
{
   "99": "Venues",
   "100": "Party Supplies",
   "101": "Entertainment",
   "102": "Desserts",
   "103": "Catering"
}
```

here, how i tried to set the data in my list.

```
const dataItem = data.data;
const newList = [];
newList.push({item: dataItem[99]});
newList.push({item: dataItem[100]});
newList.push({item: dataItem[101]});
setList(newList);
```

but when i don't have the proper name of key then how can i add it to my list?
ex. sometimes i get the key like...

```
{
    "S99": "Venues",
    "SDF100": "Party Supplies",
    "CF101": "Entertainment",
    "VF102": "Desserts",
    "CFCV103": "Catering"
}
```

So, how can i set the data in list without knowing the item key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get key and value both by using following code

```
for (var key in data.data) {
   console.log(key); // This will return a key, in your case it will be S99, SDF100...
   console.log(JSON_Obj[key]); // This will return value for that key.
   newList.push({item: data.data[key]});
}
```

from this you can add values in your list

Comment: Thank you Ravi, This is worked.. I hope this will help others. #Respect.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
 "S99": "Venues",
 "SDF100": "Party Supplies",
 "CF101": "Entertainment",
 "VF102": "Desserts",
 "CFCV103": "Catering"
}

const list = Object.values(data);
console.log(list);

// print (5) ['Venues', 'Party Supplies', 'Entertainment', 'Desserts', 'Catering']
```

Comment: Change Const to const, cuz it's crashing.

Comment: Thank's Roy Christo this is also works, appreciate your work. i'll be in connect with you thank you!